# Spark: which directory spark-submit will take to find --files?

Tags: apache-spark

I saw that we can use `spark-submit --files` to add files to the job. It's not a problem if I specify the absolute path like `spark-submit --files /etc/somescript.sh`.

But what directory it will search for if I just put `spark-submit --files somescript.sh` ? Is it the current workplace folder or all the classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Spark will search the specified file in the current folder.

You can check the code flow on spark's github repo.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala#L402

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L2069

Comment: Thank you, I read some code in a project, it's using --files someFile, but I cannot find someFile in its folder, in this case how the relative path is possible (if we look at the source code it's indeed searching in current folder)??

Comment: If the file is not present then spark job will fail.

Comment: spark will distribute the file among all executors and will put it into the execution directory. if you will try to reference the file using the absolute path it will fail (from executors). You will need to specify just the file name in such a case. Personally, I prefer to put the file into the current directory (less headache).